# Set referrer with php header( 'Location: ')

Tags: php, header, referer

Is there a way to fake referrer with header( 'Location: ') command ?

Comment: What ? what fake ? and some code

Comment: Where do you want to fake referrer?  Is your server getting the data or is your html getting the data from client side?

Answer (score 1):

Why, yes of course. You can set any header you like using the `header()` function, including Referrer. It's not really fake though - there is no rule that says you have to include a referrer header, or that you must provide truthful information in it. It's just sometimes useful.